# og:event event:start_time not working

Tags: facebook

I have 
`<meta property="og:type" content="event" />`
and the Object Graph Object Debugger from faceboook tells me `type is invalid because a required property 'event:start_time' of type 'date_time' was not provided`. I cannot find in any facebook documentation what the correct form is for `event:start_time` is.

I have tried the following:-

```
<meta property="og:type"             content="event" />
<meta property="og:event:start_date" content="30/04/2017" />
```

and

```
<meta property="og:type"             content="event" />
<meta property="og:event:start_date" content="30/04/2017" />
```

and

```
<meta property="og:type"             content="event" />
<meta property="og:event:start_date" content="1490961953365" />
```

and

```
<meta property="og:type" content="event">
<meta property="og:event:start_date" content="2017-03-31T12:05:53.365Z">
```

and

```
<meta property="og:type" content="event">
<meta property="event:start_date" content="2017-03-31T12:05:53.365Z">
```

Comment: http://ogp.me/#data_types

Comment: opg.me#data_types suggests ISO 8601, which is the format used in the last 2 examples (at least it's the Javascript version of ISO 8601

Comment: _"A DateTime represents a temporal value composed of a date (year, month, day) and an optional time component (hours, minutes)"_ - no seconds, no microseconds, no timezone specifiers.

Comment: Turns out the date format in the last example (ie. `content="2017-03-31T12:05:53.365Z")` is OK, but that I should have had property="event:start_time" (ie. not event:start_date).  Maybe other og: parsers care about the presence of seconds, microseconds & timezones, but not facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Error was

`event:start_date`

should have been

`event:start_time`

ISO Date is required (as CBroe identifies). Presence of Seconds, Microseconds and Timezone not specified in http://ogp.me/#data_types